# Assembly process for common devices

Tags: mechanical-engineering, manufacturing-engineering

As part of a course I am taking I am required to draw assembly process diagrams for common devices, such as electric motors, lamps, and mechanical presses, and I am trying to get the intuition for this. Does anyone know where you can find videos that show how common devices like these are assembled?

Comment: Best guess: youtube. Another best guess: some manufacturers do videos... Or go to the scrap yard, get a motor and take it apart, then consider the re-assembly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solar Mike's idea is best. Many (mechanical) engineers got started by taking complicated things apart when they were kids, and insights into how things get put together is best learned by taking things apart.

Comment: The taking apart is easier than the reassembly!